# How to check for duplicate code in the same file?

Tags: python, static-analysis, pylint

When I have multiple .py files, I can use `pylint --enable=duplicate-code` to check for duplicate code between different files. But how can I check if there is duplicate code within one single Python file?

(See this Github issue for instance, https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2697)